# Regex match all with delimiter

Tags: python, regex

The effect I want: fail if `x` isn't found before `y`.

```
import re

a = '''START aaaadkdklfje VALUE aaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfje aaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfje aaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfje          aaaadkdklfje
aaaadkdklfje
aaaadkdklfje condition a
aaaadkdklfje
aaaadkdklfje
aaaadkdklfje condition b
                          aaaadkdklfje z
                          aaaadkdklfjeaaaadkdklfje        aaaadkdklfjeqqqsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfsdfsdf 
condition c

???kjij
START...'''

b = re.findall(r'START condition a (VALUE).+?condition b.+?condition c(?!START)', a, re.DOTALL)
if b:
    for x in b:
        print x
```

I want to capture `value` only when `condition`s in its text block are present. Without matching past the next `start`.

This is the only case that should match:

```
start
?, value, ?, condition a, ?, condition b, ?, condition c # i want the matching to be done only in here
start
...
```

Not this:

```
start
?, value, condition a, ?
start
?, value, ?, condition b, condition c
start
```

Comment: question is unclear for me..

Comment: same here, I don't understand the question

Comment: Should conditions always be in the same order (a, b, c), or they may have a different order (b, c, a) or (c, a, b)?

Comment: @Jonny5 Yes, that looks like it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine several [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for not skipping `START` and maintaining condition sequence:

```
(?s)START(?:(?!START|condition).)*?\b(VALUE)(?=(?:(?!START).)*?condition a(?:(?!START).)*?condition b(?:(?!START).)*?condition c)
```

[Test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pO8lS2/1) but note, that this is of awful performance :]

This does allow `condition a condition a condition b condition c`. To make exclusive conditions, change `condition a(?:(?!START).)*?` and b c parts to `condition a(?:(?!START|condition).)*?`...

Comment: Oh, so between every expression, it checks for `start` after every character? Funny

Comment: using `(?:(?!START|condition).)*?` is a little redundant because you use at the same time `|condition` *and* a non-greedy quantifier. Your pattern will be better if you use `(?:(?!START|condition).)*` or `(?:(?!START).)*?`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you mean at the start and something like `START condition b VALUE ...condition a... b... c` is fine? If I change to greedy it shows more steps.

Comment: I believed you had putted `(?:(?!START|condition).)*?` everywhere. No, for the first use `(?:(?!START|VALUE).)*`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see! but this would allow a `condition` to appear before `VALUE` I'm not sure, I better leave it as it is. Feel free to edit :] or post answer.

Answer (score 2):

An other way consists to use several steps:

- you split the string with `START` to obtain a list of blocks
- you filter blocks that doesn't have the conditions
- you insert 'START' before each items.

```
blocks = re.split(r'\bSTART\b', s)
blocks = filter(lambda x: re.search(r'condition a.*?condition b.*?condition c', x), blocks[1:])
blocks = map(lambda x: 'START'+x, blocks)
```

Note: if you want the conditions to be after the keyword `VALUE`, add `\bVALUE\b.*?` at the beginning of the search pattern.

Comment: @Jonny5: to be honest, I really don't know!

Comment: I'll try profiling the two approaches and post which is faster.

Comment: @user193661: in this case try to compile the search pattern before.

Comment: 1 run @ 810kb: Jonny5: 0.22, CasimiretHippolyte: 0.02
5 run @ 25mb: Jonny5: 45.2, CasimiretHippolyte: 4.9
I replaced line 3 with `b = [re.search(p3, x).group(1) for x in blocks]`